# C# and Sparx EA interop lib - method not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, runtime, enterprise-architect

Try to compile C# code with method `RepositoryType()` which is described here
http://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/13.0/automation/repository3.html

And I got this error
[image]

> Error  CS1061  'Repository' does not contain a definition for 'RepositoryType' and no extension method 'RepositoryType' accepting a first argument of type 'Repository' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I tried to cleaning/rebuiling all stuff, but its not working. Also, during runtime call looks fine - returns string.

What could help?

UPD:

Usings and assignation

```
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
    using System.Xml.Linq;
    using EA;
    using MSScriptControl;

    public class SparxEaDocGenScriptRunner
    {
        private MSScriptControl.ScriptControl _msScriptControl;
        private EA.Repository _repository;
        private string _language;
        private string _databaseType;
        private Regex _eaLanguageDeterm;
        private Regex _getExtFromName;
        private IDictionary<string, string> _languageExts;

        /// <summary>
        /// Add-in logger accessor.
        /// </summary>
        private ApplicationLogger _logger;

        public SparxEaDocGenScriptRunner(Repository repository, ApplicationLogger logger)
        {
            _repository = repository;

            _logger = logger;

            var connectionString = _repository.ConnectionString;
            var type = _repository.RepositoryType();
        }

        //...
     }
```

And its injected all way from this part of code in, lets say, `Main.cs`:

```
public void EA_MenuClick(EA.Repository Repo, string Location, string MenuName, string ItemName)
        {
            switch (ItemName)
            {
                case MENU_DOC_GEN:
                    #region Logging Statement
                    Logger.Write(new LogEntry
                    {
                        Severity = TraceEventType.Information,
                        Message = "Loading Document Generator",
                        Categories = new[] { ApplicationConstants.DocumentGeneratorLogCategory }
                    });
                    #endregion
                    DocumentGenerator docgen = new DocumentGenerator(Repo);
                    docgen.ShowDialog();
                    break;
                case MENU_ABOUT:
                    new AboutBox().Show();
                    break;
            }
        }
```

UPD2:

My `EA.Interop.dll` version:

[image]

Comment: which framework are you targeting? (If you are targeting a client profile framework, try targeting the non-client profile)

Comment: @Hue pardon? What do you mean by that? There are only one `EA.Interop.dll` which I use there

Comment: right-click your project -> properties. What appears under Target framework?

Comment: @Hue oh,`NetFramework 4.5`

Comment: show your usings and your _repository declaration and assignation

Comment: @Hue wellp, its injected. But I'll show how it passed and where 1st time declared

Comment: I'd be surprised if that was your problem, but you have a local variable named Repository, try renaming it to repository (without the capital), or repo like I do, this will at least clear some confusion in your code

Comment: @Hue wellp, its not a problem, other functions work fine

Comment: on my end it compiles (although I dont have those libraries: Extensible Document, AptDocGenReport, ApplicationLogger)

Comment: @Hue wellp, its just custom libs which about working with WordAutomation. They not impact, so, let's pretend that they are not there :) Oh yeah, and that function fails to be called since very beginning, in `EA_MenuClick` so

Comment: @Hue hmm, what version do you got? I put mine at the end of question

Comment: I tested it on 4.5 for your docgen class, but I fell like its not working ebcause one of the libraries I dont have have a Repository type that may conflict with EA's, if that's not the case, then I don't know. You can try putting EA.Repository in in the doc gen constructor instead of just Repository

Comment: @Hue yeah, strange things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote to support, referenced on my qusetion here, and got my answer :) It really helped. And I was too careless, again.

> Hi Danil,
>
> Thank you for your enquiry.
>
> It's possible that you are referencing an older version of the
>   EA.Interop.dll file which did not yet contain this function. We could
>   see in your screenshot that you are referencing this Interop DLL from
>   somewhere under "C:\Users\temp1...".
>
> Please note that the version number of the EA.Interop.dll file doesn't
>   get updated between EA versions, it is generally more useful to look
>   at the created/modified timestamp on the file. What are the timestamps
>   on the Interop DLL file you are referencing and the one in your
>   current EA install directory? (default: C:\Program Files (x86)\Sparx
>   Systems\EA)
>
> I would suggest either changing your reference to point directly to
>   the DLL from your current EA installation, or copy the current version
>   from your EA install directory and overwrite the location where your
>   dll is being referenced from.
>
> Best regards,
>
> Aaron Bell
>
> Sparx Systems Pty Ltd
>
> support@sparxsystems.com
>
> http://www.sparxsystems.com

Well, so I reinstalled Sparx EA, copied .dll from installation folder and it worked!

Comment: @Hue well, its on my VM so, user name is temp. And the .dll and how it was included there (and whole project) is from repo, so

Comment: but my guess is you had the installation of EA for a while which is why the dll was outdated